# Converting sentence to predicate logic.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Let S(x) :- x is a student **and**
      Exam(x,y) :- x gave exam in stream y.

The statement is ' There does not exist a student who has given exam in every stream '

I thought to negate this sentence so that i can convert it easily.

1) Not ( There exists a student who has given exam in every stream).

2) Not ( There exists a student who has not given exam in at least one stream).

I am not sure which of the above 2 is correct. While negating should I negate only the 'exists' part or whole thing including 'exists'  like in 2nd sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Statement can be expressed as: $$\neg (\exists x( S(x) \wedge \forall y E(x,y)))$$ using the first interpretation which is the correct negation of the intended statement.

Comment: But when we apply NOT to the entire sentence, so everything should be negated inside it right ? Why is 2nd interpretation not correct?

Comment: @RajeshR Note that the meaning of the second statement is itself totally different from the original. Read it once and see.

Comment: @RajeshR You just apply the negation to the existence. $$\underbrace{\text{There does not exist }}_{\neg\exists x}\underbrace{\text{ a student who has }}_{S(x)\wedge}\underbrace{\text{ given exam in every stream }}_{\forall y~E(x,y)}$$ Though you *may* then use quantifier duality to "move the negation".  $$\underbrace{\text{For all }}_{\forall x}\underbrace{\text{ students who have }}_{S(x)\to}\underbrace{\text{ not given an exam in some stream }}_{\exists y~\neg E(x,y)}$$